# Select Radio Buttons in Selenium Webdriver [C#]

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have this HTML

```
<div class="Radio">
 <label>
  <input class id="checkbox" name="category" type="radio" value="1">
  <strong> TONY STARK </strong>
 </label>

 <label>
  <input class id="checkbox" name="category" type="radio" value="2">
  <strong> IRON MAN </strong>
 </label>

 <label>
  <input class id="checkbox" name="category" type="radio" value="3">
  <strong> ROBERT DOWNEY </strong>
 </label>
```

I need to select radio buttons based on `TONY STARK` , `IRON MAN` , `ROBERT DOWNEY` as the user passes it as a flexible parameter

I tried this, but any other easy way would definitely help me!

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("checkbox"));
for(WebElement radiobutton: radiobuttons)
{ 
  if(radiobutton.getAttribute("value").equals("TONY STARK"))
  radiobutton.click();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try using `Xpath` to get single radio button and avoid looping as below :-

```
string Xpath = ".//input[following-sibling::strong[contains(.,'TONY STARK')]]";
```

Or

```
string Xpath = ".//label[contains(.,'TONY STARK')]/input";
```

Use any one of these `Xpath` to find radio button as :

```
var radio = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath(Xpath));
radio.Click();
```

Comment: Awesome, That worked out! So, @Saurabh, how do i find the text by **`value`** ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand what are you asking?? By which value do you want to find text??

Answer (score 2):

You can use xpath to do that. Try the below xpath `.//label[contains(text(),'TONY STARK')]/input[@id='checbox']`

Answer (score 2):

Create a class to wrap up radios from now on:

```
public class RadioButtons
{
    public RadioButtons(IWebDriver driver, ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> webElements)
    { 
        Driver = driver;
        WebElements = webElements;
    }

    protected IWebDriver Driver { get; }

    protected ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> WebElements { get; }

    public void SelectValue(String value)
    {
        WebElements.Single(we => we.GetAttribute("value") == value).Click();
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
RadioButtons categories = new RadioButtons(Driver, driver.FindElements(By.Name("category")));

categories.SelectValue("TONY STARK");
```

Answer (score 2):

I have this other solution:

```
public void RadioButtonClickByNameAndValue(string name, string val)
        {
            ScreenComponent.Wait.WaitVisibleElement(By.Name(name));
            ScreenComponent.Script.ExecuteJavaScriptCode($"$('[name={name}][value={val}]').click();");
        }
```

- In another class I say what value I want to click and in another class I say what is the element.
- in my case the radio options value are "True" and "False".

Answer (score 0):

Identify a radio button using XPath with index

```
IWebElement radioButton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@type='radio'][1]");
radioButton.Click();
```

where:

Asterisk * means wildcard character.

[1] is the position of radio button options ("TONY STARK")